# Decompose a number into a sum of repdigits

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, number

Repdigits are numbers of the form `a * (10^n - 1)/9` with  `a in [-9,9]\{0}` (in other words 111, -3333, 66, numbers which are made by repeating only one digit)

**Goal:** Write a program or function which takes a single positive integer `N` and prints `N = s_1 + s_2 + ... + s_k`. There should be one number per line and the numbers need to be right-aligned. No two summands should have the same number of digits and adding zeros is not allowed. The output should be ordered in ascending or descending order (by number of digits)

**Examples:**

```
in:
24192
out:
24192 =
22222 +
 2222 -
  222 -
   33 +
    3

in:
24192
out:
    -7
   -22
  +888
 +1111
+22222
=24192

in:
113
out:
113=    NOT  111+  no empty lines  111+
111+          00+                    
  2            2                     2
```

As you can see there can be multiple solutions and some artistic freedom is allowed. Leading and trailing whitespace in each line is allowed

Shortest byte count wins

Comment: Should you declare some rules to prevent e.g. just printing `N` ones?

Comment: This is covered already: "No two summands should have the same number of digits"

Comment: These numbers are also called repdigits.

Answer (score 6):

## perl 5 - <strike>97 92 93</strike> 86

```
$x=$_=pop;{printf"%15s
",$_;$_=$x,s!\d!//,$&!eg,$x-=$_,$i++?s/^\b/+/:s/^/=/;/0/||redo}
```

Input given as a parameter:

```
$perl a.pl 2224192
     2224192
    =2222222
       +1111
        +888
         -22
          -7
```

Comment: It doesn't print anything if the number has a 0 in it. Maybe it's the `/0/` looping condition.

Comment: Thanks, indeed that is the case. I confused myself with the perl shortcut loops. They have condition at the end but still check it at the first iteration. I have to look for "+0" then.

Comment: Actually I can simulate do ... while() with just one extra character using `redo`.

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, <s>55</s> 50 bytes

```
'=l:L+Li{_W>"-+"=1$zs(\,)*+:Ii-L,_S*I+\~>\}h;]W%N*
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Uses the output format

```
      -7
     -22
    +888
   +1111
+2222222
=2224192
```

I might golf this more once I'm beaten.

Explanation:

```
'=l:L+Li{_W>"-+"=1$zs(\,)*+:Ii-L,_S*I+\~>\}h;]W%N*
'=                                                 "Push = character.";
  l:L                                              "Read STDIN and store in L.";
     +L                                            "Concatenate, push new copy of L.";
       i                                           "Convert to integer.";
        {                                 }h       "Do-while loop. Leaves the condition on the
                                                    stack. I will use the remainder for that.";
         _W>                                       "Duplicate remainder, compare with -1.";
            "-+"=                                  "Select appropriate sign character.";
                 1$                                "Copy remainder again.";
                   zs                              "Take abs() and convert to string.";
                     (                             "Shift off first digit.";
                      \                            "Swap with string.";
                       ,                           "Get length.";
                        )                          "Increment.";
                         *                         "Repeat digit that often.";
                          +                        "Concatenate with sign.";
                           :I                      "Store in I.";
                             i-                    "Convert to integer. Subtract from remainder.";
                                                   "Now we'll right-justify I.";
                               L,                  "Load input, get length.";
                                 _                 "Duplicate.";
                                  S*               "Repeat space that often.";
                                    I+             "Load string and concatenate.";
                                      \~           "Swap with length. Bitwise complement.";
                                        >          "Take that many characters from the right.";
                                         \         "Swap with remainder.";
                                            ;      "Discard final remainder (0).";
                                             ]     "Wrap in array.";
                                              W%   "Reverse.";
                                                N* "Join with line feeds.";
```

The resulting array is printed automatically at the end of the program.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript ES6 - 145

```
i=0;f=n=>{return g=n<0,n=Math.abs(n)+'',l=n.length,r=l-1?n[0].repeat(l):n,(i>0?g?'-':'+':n+'=')+'\n'+' '.repeat(i++)+(l-1?r+f((+n-r)*(g?-1:1)):r)}
```

Paste into Firefox console. Run as `f(24192)`.

Output for `f(24192)`:

```
24192=
22222+
 1111+
  888-
   22-
    7
```

Comment: With the input `55` it includes a 0 in the sum (which is a bug).

Answer (score 0):

### GolfScript 77

```
~.[{..0>2*(.@*`.,\[0=]*''+~*.@\-.}do;]-1%{[.0>' +'=\`n].1=,2$`,\-' '*\+}%'='@
```

Online demo links:

- [24192](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OycyNDE5MicKCn4uW3suLjA%2BMiooLkAqYC4sXFswPV0qJycrfiouQFwtLn1kbztdLTEle1suMD4nICsnPVxgbl0uMT0sMiRgLFwtJyAnKlwrfSUnPSdA&run=true)
- [2147483648](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OycyMTQ3NDgzNjQ4JwoKfi5bey4uMD4yKiguQCpgLixcWzA9XSonJyt%2BKi5AXC0ufWRvO10tMSV7Wy4wPicgKyc9XGBuXS4xPSwyJGAsXC0nICcqXCt9JSc9J0A%3D&run=true)
- [1 trillionth prime](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OycyOTk5NjIyNDI3NTgzMycKCn4uW3suLjA%2BMiooLkAqYC4sXFswPV0qJycrfiouQFwtLn1kbztdLTEle1suMD4nICsnPVxgbl0uMT0sMiRgLFwtJyAnKlwrfSUnPSdA&run=true)

A slightly more readable version (if GolfScript can be called readable) with unit tests version is available [here](https://github.com/clupascu/codegolf/blob/9cc152756fffb96f59a1cb8fea2e0816b6cc1739/decompose_number_in_repdigits/decompose.gs).